# SSL Cerificate: How we can make website insecure for browser

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

Here are some doubts about the ssl certificates. As per my understanding, we have pre installed some certificates in browser key chain area. When we open website, it will verify the certificate which is returns from that particular domain with itself certificates. If the intermediate ca is authorized then it shows secure website otherwise it will show insecure.

I just want to to make website insecure for me which is secured already. For that i have deleted certificates from my browser area but still browser is showing a secure website.

Website certificate

[image: Website certificate]

My browser certificates

[image: Browser certificates]

As you can see website is using certificate which is signed by intermediate authority **comodo rsa organization validation secure service CA**. This authority is no more longer in my browser certificates area, i have removed it.

So could you help me guys why browser is still showing that website secure?

Comment: What about "COMODO Secure ™️"? Is it still in browser/system trusted certificate list? What is it's issuer?

Comment: This certificate still in the browser area but i am not able to remove it. Remove button is disabled in browser.

Comment: So if root certificate is trusted, all certificates issued by it/or it's leaf certificates are trusted too. You need to remove it/disable it somehow if you want to finish your test

Comment: So yes i disabled all the comodo certificates but it doesn't show insecure. But when we click on certificate it shows certificate is disabled.